# Synchronous requestAnimationFrame does not cohere with timeout

Tags: javascript, html, callback, settimeout, requestanimationframe

I have a webpage composed of two divs: one contains canvases (named 'gratings'), the other simply has a question mark (named 'qmark').

there's a set of functions and an algorithm to follow:

1. prepare the canvases (using **paintSines**(signal) function)
2. immediately when canvases are ready, show them and hide everything else.
3. wait 250ms (which is the value of **minTime** variable)
4. ASAP hide the canvases and show a question mark.
5. wait a bit more (**maxTime**), then proceed (using **proceed**() function).

so I have the **setQuestion** function to handle step 1 and call the step 2 function:

```
function setQuestion(){
    paintSines(signal);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
        showQuestion();
    });
}
```

**showQuestion** is handling step 2+3, then calling another function:

```
function showQuestion(){
    document.getElementById('qmark').hidden = true;
    document.getElementById('gratings').hidden = false;
    setTimeout(waitResp,minTime);
}
```

finally **waitResp** handles steps 4+5:

```
function waitResp(){
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
        document.getElementById('gratings').hidden = true;
        document.getElementById('qmark').hidden = false;
    });
    setTimeout(proceed, maxTime);
}
```

this is the webpage body:

```
<body>
    <div id="gratings">
        <canvas id="upperCanvas"></canvas>
        <canvas id="lowerCanvas"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div id="qmark">
        <h1>?</h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

The reason for separation is that this is a shared piece of code and **showQuestion** is implemented differently on various occasions.

I need the algorithm steps to occur synchronously and I cannot use jQuery (suppose bind() would have done it). What I get is that instead of showing the canvases for 250ms, it barely shows them for 170ms. I have suspected that the requestAnimationFrame is called before paintSines has done so I've tried passing it as a callback, that didn't do any good:

```
function setQuestion(){
    paintSinesWithCallback(s.getCurrentSignal(),bla);

    function paintSinesWithCallback(signal,callback){
        paintSines(signal);
        callback();
    }   

    function bla(){
        window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
          showQuestion();
        });
  }
}
```

any ideas?

EDIT:
trying to remove the `requestAnimationFrame` from **waitResp** didn't change anything:

```
function waitResp(){
    document.getElementById('gratings').hidden = true;
    document.getElementById('qmark').hidden = false;
    run = setTimeout(proceed,maxTime);
}
```

strange thing is, when trying to log execution times it seems that is does wait 250ms but analyzing the video record of the screen shows a wait of only ~170ms

Comment: What is `paintSines` doing?

Comment: paints each canvas line-by-line. this is done using a bunch of functions from the **Painter** object, which I have created.

Comment: You use `requestAnimationFrame` in wrong way. It's usage implies **single** recurrent loop containing **single** `requestAnimationFrame` call. Any extra calls of `requestAnimationFrame` or `setTimeout` are undesirable.

Comment: @hindmost kindly refer edit.

Comment: So what is your actual problem? Refactor the code to make it run syncly, or analyze execution logs?

Comment: it doesn't run syncly as it should, as reflected in execution logs.